# SEC dataset missing tags compared to company XBRL submission file

Tags: tags, dataset, xbrl

I am trying to get financial info specifically XBRL tags from SEC dataset: https://www.sec.gov/dera/data/financial-statement-data-sets.html, and I was able to found around 328 tags, 89 non-repeated ones. merge sub with num, find all tags in the sub_num files

```
company = 1166126
sub_s_f = sub[(sub.cik == company)]`
jcp_num = num[(num.adsh == '0001166126-15-000055')]
jcp_num_tag_list = jcp_num.tag.tolist() 
jcp_num_tag_set = set(jcp_num_tag_list_new)
```

However, when I tried to find all tags in JCPENNEY'S XBRL submission file, ftp://ftp.sec.gov/edgar/data/1166126/0001166126-15-000055.txt. I was able to find around 858 tags, 180 non-repeated ones.

```
all_tags = soup.find_all(re.compile("\w"), attrs={"unitref":re.compile("\w")})
```

Now I am confused and wonder if anyone knows whether SEC eliminates any tags before it groups them into dataset.

Would appreciate any thoughts or feedbacks!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand it, the SEC documents the num documents as only including numeric facts (from readme.htm):

> NUM is a data set of all numeric XBRL facts presented on the primary
>   financial statements

Your second query above seems to filter unit references, hence numeric facts as well. If I run queries on the raw filing, I also find 858 numeric facts (= what you call non-unique tags) and 179 unique non-abstract numeric concepts (= non-repeated numeric tags). So this tends to show that your second query does it right.

So yes, some of these tags are not in the data set: there are numeric tags such as us-gaap:InterestRateCashFlowHedgeGainLossReclassifiedToEarningsNet that do not appear in num.txt.

Looking further, this tag belongs to the component: 2408405 - Disclosure - Stockholders' Equity (Reclassifications Out of Accumulated Other Comprehensive Income/ (Loss) (Details).

Now, the SEC also says:

> The scope of the data in the financial statement data sets consists of [...] Numeric data on the primary financial statements (Balance Sheet,
>   Income Statement, Cash Flows, Changes in Equity, and Comprehensive
>   Income) and page footnotes on those statements;

So the answer may be that the tags not belonging to these primary financial statements are excluded from the data set.